# Asking grammar checking questions, OK or not

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I'm not a native English speaker and I have always doubts about whether my English text is grammatically correct or not. I've searched for online grammar checker websites but I can't find a fully intelligent website. Also I've tried Google translation service but it won't help me too.

Now my question is:
Would it be OK to share my some English texts in this website and ask for grammar checking? But seems here is not the place I'm looking for, If so, where can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the website [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/) It has excellent resources and very focussed forums (or *fora* if you're being nit-picky...). I rarely see idle chit-chat whenever I visit. But from what I gather, you are allowed to ask for equivalent idioms, phrases, expressions etc. It is NOT a proofreading service. Proofreading is a serious and time consuming activity, I would not do it without being paid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Great suggestion, thanks

Comment: See [Should we require grammaticality judgement questions to explain who told them something might not be grammatical?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/5366/59258)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because ELU is not a proofreading service, questions asking whether something is correct are off-topic. They would be of no help to anyone but the asker, and would not add value to the site.

However, if you could instead recast such questions into asking about a more general matter, something that could apply to other people and situations than your own, perhaps with example texts demonstrating the point you have questions about, then they become on topic again.

That does not mean they are not duplicates.  But at least they would no longer be proofreading.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so could you please offer me somewhere online where I can ask such questions?

Comment: @abforce We get asked that a lot, and the short answer is we don't know. The people on EL&U, by and large, do not need such services, so they haven't searched for them online. A couple of our regular members *are* in the business of teaching EFL, but they tend to do so face-to-face with students, as a paid service, rather than anonymously online, for free.